Browser caching with local storage not working in i18next
I'm trying to use i18next caching solution but it is not clear to me what is wrong because I don't see the storage in browser's Application tab.
This project does not contain a backend. It's a self-contained web component with plain Javascript.
Here's the code.
import i18next from 'i18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import LocalStorageBackend from 'i18next-localstorage-backend';
import ChainedBackend from "i18next-chained-backend";

let initialized = false;
const userLocale = navigator.language.split('-')[0];

export function initTranslation() {
  if (!initialized) {
    i18next
    .use(resourcesToBackend((lng, ns) => import(`./my/path/common-${lng}.json`), 'commonResource'))
    .use(ChainedBackend)
    .init({
      debug: true,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      lng: userLocale,
      backend: {
        backends: [LocalStorageBackend],
        backendOptions: [{
          projectId: 'mytranslation',
          expirationTime: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 7 days
        }]
      }
    });
    initialized = true;
  }

